# Criar RadioGroup baseado em seleção de ComboBox utilizando INI, dinamicamente em Delphi

Tags: delphi-7, combobox

**Contexto:**
Com a utilização de uma aplicativo pessoal feito em [delphi-7](/questions/tagged/delphi-7), fui adicionando novas ações conforme necessidade em um `TRadioGroup`, porém agora contém muitos itens (16), prejudicando a [usabilidade](/questions/tagged/usabilidade) da aplicação.

O que eu queria fazer seria categorizar esse itens do `TRadioGroup` em um `TComboBox`, assim teria algumas categorias e o `TRadioGroup` ficaria com 
menos opções, assim melhorando a disposição visual e facilitando a escolha.

**Necessidade:**
Criar um `TComboBox` dinamicamente baseado em um arquivo `.ini`, como se
fosse uma configuração para carregamento do `TComboBox, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
[CATEGORIA]
0=CATEGORIA1
1=CATEGORIA2
2=CATEGORIA3
```

Com a categoria definida e carregando no `TComboBox` então carregar os itens do `TRadioGroup` com base no grupo, um `.ini`, mais ou menos assim, pensei:

```
[CATEGORIA_1]
0=ITEM1
1=ITEM2

[CATEGORIA_2]
0=ITEM1
1=ITEM2
2=ITEM3
3=ITEM4
4=ITEM5

[CATEGORIA_3]
0=ITEM1
1=ITEM2
2=ITEM3
```

---

Atualmente meu código utilizando o INI é somente para salvar a ultima opção selecionada, e ao reabrir o programa já trazer:

**.INI**

```
[CONFIG]
INDEXGROUP=1
```

**`Procedure SalvarINI`**:

```
procedure SalvarINI;
var
   vlIni: TIniFile;
begin
  try
    vlIni := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName) +'\'+ ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName)+'.ini');
    try
      vlIni.WriteInteger('CONFIG', 'INDEXGROUP',rgItens.ItemIndex);

      vlIni.UpdateFile;
    finally
      vlIni.Free;
    end;
  except
    on e: exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage('Ops..não conseguimos Salvar as configurações: '+ e.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**`carregarINI`**

```
procedure carregarIni;
var
  vlIni: TIniFile;
begin
  vlIni := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName) +'\'+ ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName)+'.ini');

  try
    RGProduto.ItemIndex := vlIni.ReadInteger('CONFIG' ,'INDEXGROUP',1);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(vlIni);
  end;
end;
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver o problema, deveria ter uma forma de carregar os `TComboBox` assim com base no .ini já criado:

```
[CATEGORIA]
0=CATEGORIA1
1=CATEGORIA2
2=CATEGORIA3
```

Um `for` resolveria, mas para cada categoria deveria carregar o seu itens, então sendo necessário mais um `for`. Mudei um pouco o `.ini` dos itens para ficar mais fácil o algoritmo:

```
[CATEGORIA_1]
0ITEM=DESCRICAOITEM0CAT1
1ITEM=DESCRICAOITEM1CAT1

[CATEGORIA_2]
0ITEM=DESCRICAOITEM0CAT2
1ITEM=DESCRICAOITEM1CAT2
2ITEM=DESCRICAOITEM1CAT2

[CATEGORIA_3]
0ITEM=DESCRICAOITEM0CAT3
1ITEM=DESCRICAOITEM1CAT3
2ITEM=DESCRICAOITEM2CAT3
```

Então criei um procedimento para resolver isso dinamicamente:

```
procedure TFormF.carregaRadioGroup;
var
  i,j : Integer;
  strValGrupo,
  strProdutos : TStringList;
  vlCopy : String;
  vlGrupoProduto : String;
  count : integer;
  LIni: TIniFile;
begin

  strValGrupo := TStringList.Create;
  strProdutos := TStringList.Create;

  try
    rgDinamicoProduto.Items.Clear;
    LIni := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName) +'\'+ ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName)+'.ini');

    if LIni.SectionExists('CATEGORIA') then
    begin
      LIni.ReadSection('CATEGORIA',strValGrupo);

      for i:=1 to strValGrupo.Count do
      begin
        vlGrupoProduto := 'CATEGORIA_'+IntToStr(i-1);

        if LIni.SectionExists(vlGrupoProduto) then
        begin
          LIni.ReadSection(vlGrupoProduto, strProdutos);

          if (cbGrupo.ItemIndex = i-1) then
          begin
            count := trunc(strProdutos.Count/3);
            for j:=1 to (count) do
            begin
              rgDinamicoProduto.Items.Add(LIni.Readstring(vlGrupoProduto, IntToStr(J-1)+'ITEM',''));
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LIni);
  end;
end;
```

O problema foi resolvido, mas o que vocês acham da solução?